# Email Sender Identities / Single Sender Verification

Tags: smtp, email-server

I have a self-hosted web service and one of its features is allowing customers to send emails to their customers. Currently we send these emails on behalf of our customers by setting:

from: mailer@ourdomain.com
reply-to: customer@theirdomain.com

With the proper DKIM and SPF this works, but is imperfect.

I noticed that a lot of online mail services use something that they call "Sender Identities" to accomplish sending emails on the behalf of customers more elegantly; however, I cannot find any information on how these "Sender Identities" actually work and how I would implement them myself.

Just to be clear, this does not require the verified sender to make any DNS changes themselves. It simply requires the verified sender to click a link sent to their email address that confirms they are approving the sending of emails on their behalf.  Twilio and several other mail services refer to this as Single Sender Verification.  This is an alternative to Domain Verification which would require them to make DNS changes.

My question is does anyone know how "Single Sender Verification" is implemented on the backend?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of mailserver do you use?

Comment: I use iRedMail on Debian.

Comment: Sender ID is deprecated and not widely supported, it's recommended to focus on implementing SPF, DKIM, and DMARC for better email authentication and deliverability

Comment: @Turdie which of these doesn't require DNS changes?

Comment: Wow, he doesn't say he doesn't want to make DNS changes.

Comment: Please @AlexD let's stop this discussion it doesn't help anyone. Anyway what I meant sender verification / sender id deprecated so it's better to focus on the TS on DMARC, DKIM and SPF

Comment: Is Single Sender Verification the same thing as the deprecated Sender ID?

Comment: @Turdie "Sender ID" is an old Microsoft SPF derivative, which is DNS-based and it is not what this question is about.